# Java Truststore differences between windows 7 and Solaris (Mule 3.3)

Tags: java, mule, truststore

I have two modules that I would prefer to run within the same JVM.  Both use
Mule 3.3 and both need to make https connections to specific external services.

Module A uses a specific https connector:

```
<https:connector name="proxiedHttpsConnector">
    <spring:property name="proxyHostname" value="${feeds.proxy.server}"/>
    <spring:property name="proxyPort" value="${feeds.proxy.port}"/>
    <https:tls-server path="security/modulea_store" storePassword="thesecretpassowrd"/>
</https:connector>
```

Module B uses a third party code that uses com.sun.jersey.client.apache.ApacheHttpClient (v 1.6).  Module B has been modified to work through the same proxy.

When testing Module B on Windows 7 using jdk1.6.0_27 I receive the following exception:

```
ERROR 2012-05-09 10:02:39,585 [VideoAvailable.stage1.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Component that caused exception is: DefaultJavaComponent{VideoAvailable.commponent.414853995}. Message payload is of type: VideoEvent
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. unable to find valid certification path to requested target (sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException)
  sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder:174 (null)
2. PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (sun.security.validator.ValidatorException)
  sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator:323 (null)
3. sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException)
  com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts:174 (http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLHandshakeException.html)
4. javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException)
  com.sun.jersey.client.apache.DefaultApacheHttpMethodExecutor:213 (null)
5. Component that caused exception is: DefaultJavaComponent{VideoAvailable.commponent.414853995}. Message payload is of type: VideoEvent (org.mule.component.ComponentException)
  org.mule.component.DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter:359 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/component/ComponentException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:174)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:238)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:318)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

I can add the certificate to connect to Module B's remote service to Module A's truststore and both Modules work fine on Windows 7.

Running that same configuration on SunOS 5.10 running jre 1.6.0_06 (I know it's old),
produces the following error:

```
2012/05/08 17:42:32 | ERROR 2012-05-08 17:42:32,265 [VideoAvailable.stage1.04] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
2012/05/08 17:42:32 | ********************************************************************************
2012/05/08 17:42:32 | Message               : Component that caused exception is: DefaultJavaComponent{VideoAvailable.commponent.6015177}. Message payload is of type: VideoEvent
2012/05/08 17:42:32 | Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
2012/05/08 17:42:32 | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2012/05/08 17:42:32 | Exception stack is:
2012/05/08 17:42:32 | 1. the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty (java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException)
2012/05/08 17:42:32 |   java.security.cert.PKIXParameters:183 (null)
2012/05/08 17:42:32 | 2. Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty (java.lang.RuntimeException)
2012/05/08 17:42:32 |   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator:59 (null)
2012/05/08 17:42:32 | 3. java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty (javax.net.ssl.SSLException)
2012/05/08 17:42:32 |   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts:190 (http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLException.html)
2012/05/08 17:42:32 | 4. javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty (com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException)
2012/05/08 17:42:32 |   com.sun.jersey.client.apache.DefaultApacheHttpMethodExecutor:213 (null)
2012/05/08 17:42:32 | 5. Component that caused exception is: DefaultJavaComponent{VideoAvailable.commponent.6015177}. Message payload is of type: VideoEvent (org.mule.component.ComponentException)
2012/05/08 17:42:32 |   org.mule.component.DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter:359 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/component/ComponentException.html)
2012/05/08 17:42:32 | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2012/05/08 17:42:32 | Root Exception stack trace:
2012/05/08 17:42:32 | java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
2012/05/08 17:42:32 |   at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.setTrustAnchors(PKIXParameters.java:183)
2012/05/08 17:42:32 |   at java.security.cert.PKIXParameters.<init>(PKIXParameters.java:103)
2012/05/08 17:42:32 |   at java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters.<init>(PKIXBuilderParameters.java:87)
2012/05/08 17:42:32 |     + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
2012/05/08 17:42:32 | ********************************************************************************
```

Both run fine independently on Windows 7 and SunOS.  Both run fine together on Windows 7.
Both are incompatible on SunOS.  Also, adding the certificate needed by Module B to
/NFL/ESB/apps/jdk1.6.0_06/jre/lib/security/cacerts and bouncing Mule did not help.  I have also tried to configue my Windows 7 JDK to point to a copy of the SunOS cacerts (for the default) and that did not reproduce the Sun error.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you used "\" as the path separator, thus fails on SunOS?

Comment: Appreciate the comment, no "\"s are in any paths on SunOS.  Also, I tried a more current version of the JDK on the SunOS box and the behavior is the same.  The core issue is that the default truststtore is initialized differently between Windows 7 and SunOS when running both modules.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reconfigure module A to use the default Trust Store:

```
<https:connector name="proxiedHttpsConnector"
     http:proxyHostname="${feeds.proxy.server}"
     http:proxyPort="${feeds.proxy.port}"/>
```

which then allows both modules to run together.

In terms of the primary goal, this works fine.  I never completely untangled
the different trust store initialization paths between Windows 7 and Solaris
but have spent enough time on this problem that I need to move on.